# Como puedo validar la cantidad de numeros minimos en un Array?

Tags: javascript, validación

esta funcion arroja el numero mayor y el menor de todos los ingresados por lo que quiero validar que el usuario si o si ingrese dos numeros pero no puedo conseguirlo

```
let arr = [-1, 5, 14, 0, 6];

const elevarNumeros = (arr = undefined) => {
    if (arr === undefined) return alert("Debes ingresar los numeros");
    if (!(arr instanceof Array)) return alert(`${arr} no es un número`);
    // Puse el if que sigue para tratar de validar pero no funciona
    if (length.arr < 1) return alert("Debes ingresar dos numeros o más");

    for (let num of arr) {
        if (typeof num !== "number") return alert(`${arr} no es un número`);
    }

    console.log(`El numero mas alto es el ${Math.max(...arr)} y el mas bajo ${Math.min(...arr)}`)
}

elevarNumeros(arr);
```

Comment: Las etiquetas se usan para indicar las tecnologías involucradas, por favor especifica qué lenguaje usas (javascript en este caso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya tienes la respuesta a tu problema por parte de [`@nashvent`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/413132/como-puedo-validar-la-cantidad-de-numeros-minimos-en-un-array/413138#413138)

Como comentan es un error en la *Sintaxis*.

Eh querido dejarte un añadido en cuanto a posibles errores con diferentes tipos de datos específicos que pudiera llegar a insertar el usuario.
Véase.

- undefined
- boolean
- symbol
- Infinity

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, -5]
const elevarNumeros = (arr = undefined) => {
    
    
    if (!(arr instanceof Array)) return alert(`${arr} No es un Array, es un ${(typeof arr)}.`);
 
    if (arr.length < 2) return alert("Debes ingresar dos numeros o más");

    for (let num of arr) {
        if (typeof num === "string") return alert(`${arr} no es un número`);
        // Si queires el "Infinity" puedes retirar la condicion para ello.
        if (typeof num !== 'number' || isNaN(num) || !isFinite(num)) return alert("Debes ingresar los numeros");
    }

    console.log(`El numero mas alto es el ${Math.max(...arr)} y el mas bajo ${Math.min(...arr)}`)
}

elevarNumeros(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en el tercer `if` debido a que estas accediendo al tamaño del array de forma incorrecta y se validaria que tenga mas de 1 elemento.

```
 if (arr.length < 2) return alert("Debes ingresar dos numeros o más");
```

El código completo seria:

```js
let arr = [-1];

const elevarNumeros = (arr = undefined) => {
    if (arr === undefined) return alert("Debes ingresar los numeros");
    if (!(arr instanceof Array)) return alert(`${arr} no es un número`);
    // Valida si existe menos 2 de elementos
    if (arr.length < 2) return alert("Debes ingresar dos numeros o más");

    for (let num of arr) {
        if (typeof num !== "number") return alert(`${arr} no es un número`);
    }

    console.log(`El numero mas alto es el ${Math.max(...arr)} y el mas bajo ${Math.min(...arr)}`)
}

elevarNumeros(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

intenta este codigo

```
if (arr.length >= 1) return alert("Debes ingresar dos numeros o más");
```

la etiqueta length va posterior a tu variable introducir el código aquí